# Creating table using DIVS?

Tags: html, css

Good day! I would like to ask on how can I make my table like this? 
[image]

Here's my code but unfortunately I'm having issues with the borders and rows and cells sizes. #DIVception. Thanks in advance!

```
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="div.css">

</head>



<div class="table">
<div class="rTable"> 
    <div class="rTableRow"> 
        <div class="rTableHead"><strong>Request:</strong></div> 
        <div class="rTableHead"><strong>Processing</strong></div>
        <div class="rTableHead"><strong>Job Name:</strong></div>
        <div class="rTableHead"><strong>Anthem Inventory</strong></div>
    </div> 
 </div>
 <div class="rTableMessage"> 
    <p>
            Hi,                              
            Files successfully loaded. You may now verify at your end.
            If feed files have fallouts, reason for fallouts can be seen in     
            the error message of the file. You may edit/update your file so 
            that the other fallouts can be processed by the job.
            Note:
            All updated files sent to the server will update the existing 
            stored records. Hence, there will be no reloading of the 
            previous files.                         

            Please see details below:
    </p>
 </div> 

 <div class="rTableDetails"> 
    <div class="rTableRow"> 
        <div class="rTableFallouts"><strong>Fallouts:</strong></div> 
        <div class="rTableHead">Check attachment</div>
    </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="rTableDetails"> 
    <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableLink"><strong>Link:</strong></div> 
        <div class="rTableHead">Check attachment</div>
    </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="rTableDetails"> 
    <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableBlank"></div> 
        <div class="rTableBlank2"></div>
    </div> 
 </div>

 <div class="rTableDetails"> 
    <div class="rTableRow">
        <div class="rTableLink"><strong>Details:</strong></div> 
        <div class="rTableProcess">Processed @ 5:40 PM</div>
    </div> 
 </div>




 </div> 

 </html>
```

And here's my css codes:

```
 .table {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
border-style: solid;
border-width: 1px;
}
.rTable {       
display: table;     
width: 100%; 
} 
.rTableRow {    
display: table-row; 
} 
.rTableMessage {
padding-right: 20px;
padding-left: 20px;
padding-bottom: 20px;
padding-top: 20px;
}
.rTableHead { 
display: table-cell;    
padding: 3px 10px;      
border: 1px solid #999999;
}
.rTableDetails {
display: table;     
width: 100%;    
}
.rTableFallouts, .rTableLink {
display: table-cell; 
border: 1px solid #999999;
width: 120px;
}
.rTableBlank {
display: table-cell; 
border: 1px solid #999999;
width: 120px;
height: 25px;
background-color: gray;
}
.rTableBlank2 {
display: table-cell; 
border: 1px solid #999999;
width: auto;
height: 25px;
background-color: gray;
}
.rDetails {
height: auto;
border: 1px solid #999999;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you trying to duplicate a table? I'm not sure any of that should be in one. If so, keep it in a table.

Comment: Historically, tables were abused and misused for all sorts of reasons. However, if your data is tabular then please use a table - that's what it's for!

Answer (score 0):

If you try a overflow:hidden; in .table, it should fix your problem

Answer (score 0):

sorry but I don't quite understand your problem regarding on borders and rows. But assume that you want your table be like this. Why not use `<table>` tag instead of `<div>`? Using `<table>` you can format your table the way you want it to be just like this.

http://jsfiddle.net/Lfnk0b4a/

**Note:**
If you want to show us regarding on UI you better use `jsfiddle` to show to us. In that case we can easily see the problem and solved it providing the code on your jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add a class 'row' to each row.
For example:

```
.row:nth-child(odd) {
   background-color: grey;
}
```

Here is a working sample: [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nmbvsoov/)